# Detecting whether Graphicsmagick or ImageMagick headers are included

Tags: imagemagick, c-preprocessor, graphicsmagick

I'm developing a C/C++ library that uses *ImageMagick* (using/supporting both `libMagickCore` and `libMagick++`), for reading and writing image data (*not* for processing).

Now, I would also like to support IM's *GraphicsMagick* fork (e.g. using Debian's `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` package).

Unfortunately, the APIs have diverged enough, so that I cannot use one as a drop-in replacement of the other. Since they are still quite similar, I plan to use a number of `#ifdef`s for the API specific parts.

Now my problem is, that it seems quite complicated to detect which API is actually used via pre-processor directives, right after including the generic header (which is called the same for both variants).

Basically, I'm looking for something like a `#define` (provided by the IM/GM headers) that can be used to tell the two APIs apart. Something like:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#ifdef GRAPHICSMAGIC_DEFINE
// GM-specific code
#else
// IM-specific code
#endif
```

or, for the C-API:

```
#include <magick/MagickCore.h>
#ifdef GRAPHICSMAGIC_DEFINE2
/* GM-specific code */
#else
/* IM-specific code */
#endif
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html), or [CMake](https://cmake.org).

Really - there's no simpler way around it, but you need to package your solution with something that will ask the system what library is present, and will then generate `config.h` with the correct pre-processor definitions.

The difference between GraphicsMagick & ImageMagick seem simple enough to do something clever, BUT now that we're a year into the release of IM 7, we now need to check which version & adjust definitions as needed. For example

```c
// IM 6
#include <magick/MagickCore.h>
// IM 7
#include <MagickCore/MagickCore.h>
```

I would suggest reviewing [existing m4 scripts](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagemagick.m4) used by other projects available online.

So back to the original question, the generic include headers my look something like this... (and I quote from [Imagick library](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/php_imagick_defs.h#L24), but can be expanded to cover GM)

```c
#if defined (IM_MAGICKWAND_HEADER_STYLE_SEVEN)
#  include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>
#elif defined (IM_MAGICKWAND_HEADER_STYLE_OLD)
#  include <wand/magick-wand.h>
#else
#  include <wand/MagickWand.h>
#endif
```